# Filter to exclude formula and blank

Tags: vba, filter

Filter field has many numbers, formula (result is "-") and blank.
How to write a VBA code to filter all numbers and exclude "-" and blank.
"-" is not text or string it's the result of a formula.

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Range("G8").AutoFilter Filed:=7,  Criteria2:="=" 
Range("N8").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="<>-", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
```

Comment: Thank you L42 for edit my question. I'm not good at English

Comment: Yeah not a problem but pleas see this [StackOverflow question checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to improve how you construct questions in the future. It is very important to include the code you've tried.

Comment: Ah see, that is the problem. Your working on `Range("N8")` only but you set `Field:=14`. It should be `Field:=1` or is that a typo? Btw, another thing is you used `On Error Resume Next` which ignores the error. Removing that would've given you the runtime error 1004.

Comment: yeahhhhh thank you, L42. And how to post code, my friend?

Comment: 4 spaces then the code. Or you can use the Ctrl + K shortcut here in SO.

Comment: Dear L42, when i use this code with Field 1, it's filter at Col 1, not filter in Col 14, but I use this code in a sub test with Field 1 it's ok. Because my exist Filter range form Col 1, how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Edit1:** For your example, it should be:

```
Range("N8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>-" _
    , Criteria2:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd
```

This will filter out blanks and cells with `-` as a result of formula.
Take note that you're only working one Cell N8 which only have 1 field of data.

**Edit2:** Another way to make it work is to explicitly define the range you're working on.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:N100") 'change to suit
r.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="<>-" _
    , Criteria2:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Is this what you're trying? HTH.

Comment: It's not work, you have the same code with me :((. It just Filter blank not filter "-"

Comment: Really, it works at my end. :) Btw, read my comment in your question and post the code you've tried, edit your question and add the code.

Comment: I edited my question with code, but it's not down the line. please show me how to post code better

Comment: @kobebryant I updated my answer. Please refer to Edit 2 for your question in comment.